# Linear functions vs Linearithmic functions complexity

Tags: complex-analysis, provability

Can we say `Linear functions` complexity is lower than `Linearithmic functions`? ie:

`θ(4n) < θ(nlog(n))`  for n >= 1

If so, How?

Answer (score 2):

First, your notation with the Big-O symbol is not the most conventional; to denote that the time complexity of $4n$ grows slower than that of $n\log{n}$, we would use the Little-O symbol:
$$4n \in o(n \log{n})$$
Proving this is quite trivial: since
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4n}{n \log{n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4}{\log{n}} = 0 $$
by definition we have $4n \in o(n\log{n})$.

Comment: Sorry sir, I cant understand your logic. could you help me to explain in simple terms?